# Material Table React - Disable Save during edit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My page is as below:

```
    import React, {  useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getShopConfiguration, updateShopConfiguration } from '../../../api/shopConfig'
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const ConfigurationTable = (props) => {

  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Type",
      field: "flag",
      editable: 'never'
    },
    {
      title: "Value",
      field: "value",
    }
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    if (loadingData || props.selectedShop) {
      getConfiguration(props.selectedShop);
    }
  }, [props.selectedShop, loadingData]);



  const getConfiguration = async (shop) => {
    var currentShop
    if (shop) {
      currentShop = shop.value
    }
    
    const response = await (await getShopConfiguration(currentShop)).data;
    setData(response);
    setLoadingData(false);
  }

  const tableIcons = {
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };

  const updateTableData = (newData, oldData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const dataUpdate = [...data];
        const index = oldData.tableData.id;
        dataUpdate[index] = newData;
        setData([...dataUpdate]);

        resolve();
      }, 300)
    })
  }

  const saveConfig = async () => {
    var currentShop
    if (props.selectedShop) {
      currentShop = props.selectedShop.value
    }
    await updateShopConfiguration(currentShop, data);
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <div><label className="label" >{props.configLabel}</label></div>
      <div>
        {
        {loadingData ? (
          <p>Loading Please wait...</p>
        ) : (
          <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            options={{
              toolbar: false,
              paging: false
            }}
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            editable={{
              onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => updateTableData(newData, oldData)

            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <div style={{marginTop:'50px'}}>
      <button onClick = {saveConfig} >Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default ConfigurationTable
```

When I click the pencil icon against any row in the table, whilst I am updating the column data, I want the 'Save Changes' button down below on the page to be disabled. How do I do that?

At the moment, when I click the pencil icon and am editing/entering a value in the row, at that very moment, I can press 'Save Changes' , but I need to enable the 'Save Changes' only after I have clicked the tick mark/ cross which means I am done editing the record.

Comment: I would suggest adding a state that will be true/false for example 'isEditing' that u will update state when the pencil icon is clicked and when the user "cancels" the dialog it will update state again. then pass it to the button like disabled={isEditing}

Comment: Please provide a reproductible example with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. I have added dummy rows to test and commented your API call code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import { getShopConfiguration, updateShopConfiguration } from '../../../api/shopConfig'
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { Check, Clear, Edit, ViewColumn } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const ConfigurationTable = (props) => {
  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
  const [isSaveEnabled, setIsSaveEnabled] = useState(false);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Type",
      field: "flag",
      editable: "never",
    },
    {
      title: "Value",
      field: "value",
    },
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingData || props.selectedShop) {
      getConfiguration(props.selectedShop);
    }
  }, [props.selectedShop, loadingData]);

  const getConfiguration = async (shop) => {
    var currentShop;
    if (shop) {
      currentShop = shop.value;
    }

    const response = [
      { flag: "a", value: 1 },
      { flag: "b", value: 1 },
      { flag: "c", value: 1 },
      { flag: "d", value: 1 },
    ];

    // const response = await (await getShopConfiguration(currentShop)).data;
    setData(response);
    setLoadingData(false);
  };

  const tableIcons = {
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <Check {...props} onClick={() => setIsSaveEnabled(false)} ref={ref} />
    )),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <Edit {...props} onClick={() => setIsSaveEnabled(true)} ref={ref} />
    )),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />),
  };

  const updateTableData = (newData, oldData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const dataUpdate = [...data];
        const index = oldData.tableData.id;
        dataUpdate[index] = newData;
        setData([...dataUpdate]);

        resolve();
      }, 300);
    });
  };

  const saveConfig = async () => {
    // var currentShop
    // if (props.selectedShop) {
    //   currentShop = props.selectedShop.value
    // }
    // await updateShopConfiguration(currentShop, data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label className="label">{props.configLabel}</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        {loadingData ? (
          <p>Loading Please wait...</p>
        ) : (
          <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            options={{
              toolbar: false,
              paging: false,
            }}
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            editable={{
              onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                updateTableData(newData, oldData),
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
        <button disabled={isSaveEnabled} onClick={saveConfig}>
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConfigurationTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work but fails when i try different combinations of saving/cancelling.  Gets disabled when it should be enabled. But, I'll try to update it.

Comment: I guess, it will fail when you try editing multiple rows without clicking tick mark for each row after editing.. for this case instead of using boolean flag, you can use counter.. on click of each edit/pen icon increment the counter. On click of tick decrement the counter.. save button should be enabled only when the counter is 0.